# R-language parent child relationships

Tags: r

I have a set of tables that are related (parent child relationships).
First table has two column parentID,childID. Also for childID is here parentID. From this table i can build tree structure
Second table is for Parent attributes and third table is for children attributes and values
I need solutin for sum value all children(descendants) for each(relevant) parent
Is it possible ? How R-language works with hierarchie structure ?
Thank you for you ideas

> Example
>   **TAB ParentChild**
>      ParentID;ChildID
>      1;1
>      1;2
>      2;3
>      2;4
>   **TAB Parent**
>      ParentID;ParentName
>      1;ParentOne
>      2;ParentTwo
>   **TAB Child**
>      ChildID;ChildValue
>      1;10
>      2;20
>      3;30
>      4;40
>   **Required result**
>      ParentID;SumValueChildren
>      1;30
>      2;70

Comment: Post the data objects that you are working with. Using `dput(obj)` will increase probability of a response.

Comment: The format in which you already have the data is a fine one to work from.  If you want to reformat the data somehow, you would also have a reason to do so.  State the reason and how you would like the data organized, and then we can tell you how to do it.

Comment: Have a look at the `sqldf` package. If you want more help you should include a representative sample od all three tables in your question.

Comment: You want to look at the `igraph` package. Each person is a node/vertex and the child/parent relationship is a directed edge. Add attributes (eg childValue) as node attributes, use the code in the package to walk the graph.

Comment: Thanks - igraph with neighborhood function and recursive calling is solution